# Problemas al usar Intent.putExtra Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

He tenido varios problemas al intentar generar una aplicación que tome una foto y la muestre dentro de un `ImageView` de mi `Activity`. Estoy trabajando en `API 26` y he notado que mi código falla cuando se ejecuta la siguiente opción:

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
```

Soy realmente nuevo programando en `Android` y tengo la duda si es por cómo estoy enviando la `Uri`.

Éste es el código.

```
public class ChangeImg extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "Ahorr-oink/";
    private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "Img_perfil";

    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    private final int PHOTO_CODE = 200;
    private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;

    private ImageView mSetImage;
    private Button mOptionButton;
    private RelativeLayout mRlView;

    private String mPath;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_change_img);

        mSetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_picture);
        mOptionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_options_button);
        mRlView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_view);

        if(mayRequestStoragePermission())
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
        else
            mOptionButton.setEnabled(false);


        mOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showOptions();
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean mayRequestStoragePermission() {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            return true;

        if((checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                (checkSelfPermission(CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            return true;

        if((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) || (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))){
            Snackbar.make(mRlView, "Los permisos son necesarios para poder usar la aplicación",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });

        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void showOptions() {
        final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Elegir de galeria", "Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChangeImg.this);

        builder.setTitle("Elige una opción");
        builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(option[which] == "Tomar foto"){
                    openCamera();
                }else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }else {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

        if(!isDirectoryCreated)
            isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

        if(isDirectoryCreated){
            Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            final String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

            mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                    + File.separator + imageName;


            final File newFile = new File(mPath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (requestCode){
                case PHOTO_CODE:
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                            new String[]{mPath}, null,
                            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                                }
                            });

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                    mSetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    break;
                case SELECT_PICTURE:
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    mSetImage.setImageURI(path);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS){
            if(grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(ChangeImg.this, "Permisos aceptados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mOptionButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }else{
            showExplanation();
        }
    }

    private void showExplanation() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChangeImg.this);
        builder.setTitle("Permisos denegados");
        builder.setMessage("Para usar las funciones de la app necesitas aceptar los permisos");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

`XML`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ChangeImg">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show_options_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Foto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/set_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionImagenSet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/show_options_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

En el Manifest agregué los siguiente permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien si lo que quieres es tomar una foto en ese momento con la cámara del dispositivo o recuperar una foto ya existente en un archivo. Debes aclarar ese punto. Si es tomar una foto, revisa la doc de Android, en especial el apartado [*Take a photo with a camera app*](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskCaptureIntent)  donde se explica qué código usar para tomar la foto,  y el apartado [*Get the thumbnail*](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPhotoView) donde se explica cómo manipular la foto una vez hecha.

Comment: Manejo ambas opciones dentro de un DialogInterface dependiendo la opción a elegir se inicia la acción, me funciona bien el tomar la foto de la galaria pero al intentar abrir la camara es donde falla, igual revisare las ligas que me proporcionas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tenido el mismo problema, el `intent` no tiene valor null pero la información enviada en el `intent` no es recibida en `onActionActivit()`

[image]

Te recomiendo una solución usando [getContentResolver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()) :

```
    private Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private Bitmap thumbnail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ...
      ...    
      ...
      myImageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic); 

      values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
      Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
      startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);

  }
```

de esta forma `onActivityResult()` obtiene un bitmap almacenado por [getContentResolver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()) :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me ha funcionado solo una pregunta ¿puedo especificar una ruta? diferente al directorio de imagenes.